# Split a list and print out the minimum value from both sets (excluding zeros)

Tags: python

I have a list containing 9 float values and I want to take the first 5, check if they equal to zero and then take the last 4 and check if they equal to zero. If both (first 5 and the last 4) equal to zero, I want to print [None, None]. If they don't equal to zero, then I want to print 2 minimum values, one from each sets. If only the first 5 values are zeros, then I want to print None and then print the minimum value for the last four or vice versa.

E.g.

```
a = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
```

Output:

```
[None, None]
```

or

```
a = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0567,0.55,7.678,9.678]
```

Output:

```
[none, 0.55]
```

Comment: Hello xull,

Could you show us any attemps that you have made at solving this?

Comment: for `ake the first 5, check if they equal to zero` you can use `any` like `not any(a[:5])`, rest of the logic you can code accordingly, for min and max use `min` and `max` functions

Comment: This works for most cases, however, if all values are 0, I want it to return "None" and I dont know how to go about it with that .                                                                       def minimum(float_values_list):
    mini_list = []
    upper_mini = min([x for x in float_values_list[:5] if x !=0])
    mini_list.append(upper_mini)
    lower_mini = (min([x for x in float_values_list[5:] if x !=0]))
    mini_list.append(lower_mini)
    return(mini_list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def array_process(arr):
   f5 = [x for x in arr[:5] if x > 0]
   l4 = [x for x in arr[-4:] if x > 0] 
   return min(f5) if f5 else None, min(l4) if l4 else None

a = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0567,0.55,7.678,9.678]
print(array_process(a))
```

Output:

```
(None, 0.55)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple solution to meet your criteria:

```py
def array_process(arr):
    first = arr[:5]
    second = arr[5:]
    if first.count(0.0) == 5 and second.count(0.0) == 4:
        return [None, None]
    elif first.count(0.0) == 5:
        return [None, min(second)]
    elif second.count(0.0) == 4:
      return [min(first), None]
    else:
        return [min(first), min(second)]

print(array_process([0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0567,0.55,7.678,9.678]))
```

Output:

```py
[None, 0.55]
```

Comment: With this, if all my values in my list are 0.0, it wont print (None, None)

Comment: Sorry, fixed it now :)

Comment: Did the fix work?

Comment: Thanks ankti but now I run into the another problem. I will try my best to describe it with an example.

Comment: Lets say the list is this following. a = [0.0, 2.23, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.23, 0.0, 0.0]. In this case, I would like to print [2.23, 1,23] as they are the minimum values (I want to ignore the zeros)

Comment: Does that make sense?

Answer (score -1):

[Slicing](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/brackets/slicing.html) will allow you to get the first 5 and last 4 of your list:

```
a = [0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,3.0567,0.55,7.678,9.678]
first_five = a[:5]
last_four = a[-4:]
```

Then you can calculate the `min` for each:

```
result = [min(first_five), min(last_four)]
```

And finally replace the 0s with None:

```
for i in range(2):
  if result[i] == 0:
    result[i] = None
```

You can then:

```
print(result)
```

To get your result.

Comment: That's a really interesting way of solving this problem and it almost worked. I apologise for not making it clear in the first place (English is my third language, sorrryyy), but I would like to print the minimum value from the list, which is not zero. Lets says the first five values are x = [0.0,1.23,0.0,0.0,0.0], then then minimum would be 1.23 as I want to ignore the zeros. I would only like to print None when all the values are zero if that makes sense.

Comment: That is what this code does. Did you try it?

Comment: yes. Its alright though because i got an solution. Thank you so much for helping :)